# Ordering a BST in alphabetic order and returning it as a list in SML

Tags: sml

I have this tree

```
datatype 'a newarbolbin =
  Vacio 
| Nodo of 'a newarbolbin * 'a * 'a newarbolbin;
```

and this functions to order it however I want to:

```
fun preOrden2 (Vacio) = []
  | preOrden2 (Nodo(L, r, R)) = [r] @ preOrden2(L) @ preOrden2(R);

fun inOrden2 (Vacio) = []
  | inOrden2 (Nodo(L, r, R)) = inOrden2(L) @ [r] @ inOrden2(R);

fun postOrden2 (Vacio) = []
  | postOrden2 (Nodo(L, r, R)) = postOrden2(L) @ postOrden2(R) @ [r];
```

And the tree I have to sort is the following:

```
val diccionario : (string * string) newarbolbin = Vacio
```

The first string being a Spanish word and the right one a translation to English, and I have to sort it in alphabetical order with the Spanish words, the English ones don't really matter, the function I did for this, which obviously doesn't work because I probably overthought again, is the following:

```
fun listar_orden_alfabetico (Vacio) = []
  | listar_orden_alfabetico (Nodo(L, (esp, ing), R)) = 
      if esp < listar_orden_alfabetico(L) then 
        (if listar_orden_alfabetico(L) < listar_orden_alfabetico(R) then 
           preOrden2(Nodo(L, (esp, ing), R)) 
         else 
           preOrden2(Nodo(R, (esp, ing), L)))
      else 
        (if listar_orden_alfabetico(R) < listar_orden_alfabetico(L) then 
           postOrden2(Nodo(L, (esp, ing), R)) 
         else 
           postOrden2(Nodo(R, (esp, ing), L)))
```

And just in case, this is the error I'm having:

```
stdIn:44.53-48.132 Error: operator and operand do not agree [overload - bad instantiation]
  operator domain: 'Z[OL(<)] * 'Z[OL(<)]
  operand:         'Z[OL(<)] * 'Y list
  in expression:
    esp < listar_orden_alfabetico L

stdIn:45.59-46.129 Error: operator and operand do not agree [overload - bad instantiation]
  operator domain: 'Z[OL(<)] * 'Z[OL(<)]
  operand:         'Y list * 'Y list
  in expression:
    listar_orden_alfabetico L < listar_orden_alfabetico R

stdIn:47.59-48.131 Error: operator and operand do not agree [overload - bad instantiation]
  operator domain: 'Z[OL(<)] * 'Z[OL(<)]
  operand:         'Y list * 'Y list
  in expression:
    listar_orden_alfabetico R < listar_orden_alfabetico L
```

I know it means that I'm using the function wrong, but I really don't know what to do.

---

After some changes, I added a new function I came up with this:

```
fun stringdend (Vacio) = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
  | stringdend (Nodo (L,(esp,ing),R)) = esp;

fun listar_orden_alfabetico (Vacio) = []
  | listar_orden_alfabetico (Nodo(L,(esp,ing),R)) = if esp<stringdend(L) 
                                                    then (if stringdend(L)<stringdend(R) 
                                                         then preOrden2(Nodo(L,(esp,ing),R)) 
                                                         else preOrden2(Nodo(R,(esp,ing),L)))
                                                    else (if stringdend(R)<stringdend(L)
                                                         then postOrden2(Nodo(L,(esp,ing),R)) 
                                                         else postOrden2(Nodo(R,(esp,ing),L)));

val diccionario = Nodo(Nodo(Nodo(Vacio,("hola","hi"),Vacio),("comer","eat"),Nodo(Vacio,("agucate","eggplant"),Vacio)),("agua","water"),Nodo(Vacio,("sadico","sadistic"),Vacio));
```

the result is not quite right and I still don't know why

```
val it =
  [("agua","water"),("comer","eat"),("hola","hi"),("agucate","eggplant"),
   ("sadico","sadistic")] : (string * string) list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your "binary search tree" input is *not* a binary search tree; its nodes are not ordered.
(The ordering of the nodes is what makes it a "search" tree.)

If you use a correctly constructed search tree - for instance,

```
val diccionario =
    Nodo(
        Nodo(
            Nodo(Vacio,("agua","water"),Vacio),
            ("agucate","eggplant"),
            Nodo(Vacio,("comer","eat"),Vacio)),
        ("hola","hi"),
        Nodo(Vacio,("sadico","sadistic"),Vacio));
```

an inorder traversal gives the alphabetical ordering:

```
- inOrden2 diccionario;
val it =
  [("agua","water"),("agucate","eggplant"),("comer","eat"),("hola","hi"),
   ("sadico","sadistic")] : (string * string) list
```

(You really should implement functions that construct a BST correctly, and not do it by hand.)

Answer (score 0):

You want the function `listar_orden_alfabetico` to return a `list`. If so, how is this comparison supposed to work?

```
esp < listar_orden_alfabetico(L)
```

`esp` is a `string`, and `listar_orden_alfabetico(L)` is meant to be a `list`. There is no `<` operator that can compare those two data types.